# how to implement array into text with quotation marks

Tags: php, arrays, email, for-loop, quotation-marks

i have some understanding difficulties. i have some checkboxes in html like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="a[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="a[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="a[]" value="3">
```

i like to evaluate multiple choices of a[] to see what was selected thats why i have to use an array.

okay, now the problem is: after submit i have posted that array.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $a = $_POST['a'];
}
```

further i like to set some message into another array for each value that is selected:

```
if ($a === '1'){
   $msg[] = "text1";
}
if ($a === '2'){
   $msg[] = "text2";
} and so on...
```

now i have stored these messages to the array `$msg[]`

the next step and here comes my real problem:

i like to display the whole selection in a mail that will be send. so up to that point i have:

```
$to = "a@b.cd";
$subject = "some text";
$message = "some text... 

show what was selected:

$msg

end text";...
```

so normally i know that i have to use foreach like:

```
<?php if(isset($msg)):?>
    <?php foreach($msg as $m):?> 
        <p>
        <?php echo $m;?>
        </p>
    <?php endforeach;?>
<?php endif;?>
```

to make it visible. my problem is to implement this into that message from the mail into that quotation marks.

so if there is someone who could help me out, i really would appreciate.

thanks a lot.

Comment: have u tried with  `addslashes($m)`

Comment: `if ($a === '1')` -> does this work? With the code you give it would never work.

Comment: @Jon i might be wrong but posted values are always strings

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti you are correct, but `$a` would be an array here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use string concatenation, which in PHP is done using the **.** (dot) operator.

```
$message = "some text... \n\nshow what was selected:\n\n";

foreach ($a as $b)
{
    $message .= $b . "\n";
}

$message .= "end text";
```

Furthermore you should look into your variable naming ($a isn't really descriptive), and $a is an array, so you can't do `if ($a === '1')`, you should use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

Comment: do i understand it right: if (in_array($a)){ (if $a === '1'){$msg[]="text1"... and so on? thanks so far.

Comment: @bonny no, use `if (in_array('1', $yourArray)) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
$msg = array();
foreach($a as $checked){
    $msg[$a] = "text$a";
}
```

and then

```
<?php if(isset($msg)):?>
    <?php foreach($msg as $k => $m):?> 
        <p>
        <?php echo "$k : $m";>
        </p>
    <?php endforeach;?>
<?php endif;?>
```